# Use of articles with adj.+country name

Tags: articles, proper-nouns

Often in writings, I see use of the articles "a", the" with country names preceded by adjectives: a strong China, a friendly Cyprus, the rich Paraguay, etc.
What rule is that?

Comment: "a strong China" as opposed to "a weak China".  In this case, having an adjective before the country name offers several types of China.  Without an adjective, there is only one China.

Comment: What is a difference between "rich China" and "a rich China" if it is poor now?

Comment: In 'An economically strong China', the indefinite article is used to indicate the more explicit 'a time / situation in which China is economically strong' or 'China in [such a time]'. There is only one China, so this is an idiomatic usage, for 'a phase in the history (etc) of China'. With the definite article {[Visiting the beautiful Canada](http://www.holidaypirates.com/tag/canada), 'America the beautiful'} the construction is a poetic rendering of 'the beautiful country [of]...' etc. However,

Comment: with 'This isn't the England I remember', the deletion is from 'the version of / way things are/were in /... England ...'. Deletions give rise to all kinds of peculiar structures; the overall rule is 'be alert to deleted constructions'.

Comment: Voting to close as it is too broad and general reference.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### *the* is definitive

Adjectives aside, the rule still goes for all nouns.

### *a* is not definitive (infinitive)

> The rich China

Defines China as rich.

> A rich China

Indicates an **individual** China that is rich.

---

> A small area in New York City is the China of America
>
> The population is a China in itself.

Comment: Still can't grasp, is there an article or a rule explanation?

Comment: **THE** http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/definite-article/

Comment: The link doesn't explain my question. According to it, only "China" without articles and any exceptions is possible

Comment: "The" means only one; "a" means one of many. "A strong China" implies the existence of a weak one, whereas "the strong China" — which no one will ever say, unless talking about plates — is the one and only.

Comment: Surely 'a' can be used to suggest a hypothetical situation.  E.g.  " A strong Ruritania helps keep the region stable.  A weak Ruritania would allow Freedonia to dominate."

Answer (score 0):

The articles make all the difference. Their usage with a strong China, a friendly Cyprus, and the rich Paraguay help us identify them as described by the adjective. Without the articles, Strong China, Friendly Cyprus, and the Rich Paraguay would appear as proper nouns that could mark a place of reference for someplace other than China, Cyprus or Paraguay.

There's no rule for what your asking about. Instead it's grammatically correct and clear to the reader that these places are being described and not renamed.